# Obtener los resultados insertado

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una procedimiento almacenado que guarda datos en la db, y quiero saber si existe alguna función para de cierta forma obtener ese registro que se guardo en la base de datos.

```
$sql = "CALL registrar(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stm = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$stm->bindParam(1, $this->parametro1);
$stm->bindParam(2, $this->parametro2);
$stm->bindParam(3, $this->parametro3);
$stm->bindParam(4, $this->parametro4);
$stm->bindParam(5, $this->parametro5);
$stm->bindParam(6, $this->parametro6);
$stm->bindParam(7, $this->parametro7);
$stm->execute();
```

El store procedure ejecuta algo así:

```
INSERT INTO ingresos (fechaingreso, descripcion, horasalida, visitante, servicio, nodo) VALUES ( concat(parametro1, ' ', parametro2),
parametro3, parametro4, parametro5, parametro6, parametro7);
```

Comment: deberias poner que ejecuta el procedimeinto, para saber bien que necesitas, aunque por encima creo que si guardas algun parametro y/o la llave primaria de eso luego podras hacer una consulta a la BD

Comment: Gracias por la observación jejeje.

Answer (score 2):

Acabo de encontrar una manera de hacerlo, y es usando la sintaxis

```
SELECT @@identity AS id
```

El cual devuelve el último id del último ingreso en la base datos, por lo tanto se debe usar justo después de insertar datos.

En mi código quedó algo así.

```
$sql = "CALL registrar(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stm = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$stm->bindParam(1, $this->parametro1);
$stm->bindParam(2, $this->parametro2);
$stm->bindParam(3, $this->parametro3);
$stm->bindParam(4, $this->parametro4);
$stm->bindParam(5, $this->parametro5);
$stm->bindParam(6, $this->parametro6);
$stm->bindParam(7, $this->parametro7);
$stm->execute();

//Aquí se busca el último id ingresado
$sqlid = "SELECT @@identity AS id";
$stmid = $this->db->prepare($sqlid);
$stmid->execute();
var_dump($stmid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
exit;
```

Comment: genial...eso es lo bueno

Comment: Igualmente, gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: no hay de que, ahi te di el voto para que sigas con ese animo

Answer (score 0):

Con esto traerias ese registro que insertaste, con el nombre, o bien puedes usar la fecha que seria algo mas exacto tambien ...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ingresos WHERE visitante = ?";
$stm = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$stm->bindParam(1, $this->parametro5);
$stm->execute();
```

espero te ayude Bro... ReNiceCode...